# Handle alert that appears when refreshing page

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome

I have an application written in C# it's fill some textboxes on a webpage. (Chrome)

I've implemented a basic ErrorHandler in it. I would like to refresh the page after I logged the error.

But Chrome has a `Changes you made may not be saved.` prompt so I can't refresh the page automatically. I've tried the following Arguments but none of them worked:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
```

I have an idea to put the whole Selenium webdriver instance to a separated class (currently it is in the main form) so I can reach it from the ErrorHandler class too so I can quit the driver and open it again if there is any error.

But I didn't find any C# solution.

Can You help me in this case?
Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like an alert popup that interrupts the page refresh -- you might need to handle this as an alert using the `Alerts` class. Here's how to do that in C#:

```
// attempt to refresh
driver.Navigate().Refresh();

// handle the alert & continue with the page refresh
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

You may need to invoke `WebDriverWait` on the alert first:

```
// attempt to refresh
driver.Navigate().Refresh();

// wait for the alert to exist, then handle it and continue with refresh
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

var alert = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
alert.Accept();
```

Note that `ExpectedConditions` is now obsolete in the Selenium namespace for .NET so you will need to add the NuGet package, `DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers` to access this class safely. `WebDriverWait` is still contained in the `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI` namespace.

Comment: You are awesome!
WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions did the trick!
Thank You!

Comment: How would this work if the Navigation is blocking, for example if you using Click, that results in a navigation or GoTo - if the alert blocks the navigation, then the method will just hang waiting for the navigation to complete won't it?

Comment: You would need to customize your `PageLoadStrategy` to `None`, telling driver to not wait for the navigation to complete.